# Insert Into WHERE Data in a column is specific

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am trying to Copy ALL data (columns, too) from `Table1` in to `Table2` but ONLY where `Column1` is XYZ.

I have something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
Column1='XYZ'
```

This errors telling me that `Column1` is an unknown field name.

Comment: So use the correct fields name.  This would be a column in `Table1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column names must match, so alias them as they come out of `Table1` so they match `Table2`

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT table1_column1 as table2_column1
FROM Table1
WHERE
table1_column1='XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_to (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 from table_from;
```